# How to create a function to compare values in columns across a dataset and return values from other columns across the datasets

Tags: r

First of all I'm rather new to using R, and this is my first question I post.

I have two datasets: Dataset A and dataset B.

Dataset A has 7 rows, dataset B has 3 rows.

Only column A in both dataset is the same name and the same values.
I reproduced an example of my problem with the following code:

Dataset 1:

```
 Column_1A Column_1B
1         1         a
2         1         b
3         2         b
4         2         d
5         2         f
6         3         e

Column_1A <- c(1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3)
Column_1B <- c("a", "b", "b", "d", "f", "e", "a")
Dataset_1 <- data.frame(Column_1A, Column_1B)
```

Dataset 2:

```
  Column_2A Column_2B Column_2C Column_2D
1         1         r       abc         3
2         2        12       34a        NA
3         3         d       d3d         1

Column_2A <- c(1, 2, 3)
Column_2B <- c("r", 12, "d")
Column_2C <- c("abc", "34a", "d3d")
Column_2D <- c(3, NA, 1)
Dataset_2 <- data.frame(Column_2A, Column_2B, Column_2C, Column_2D)
```

I want to compare the value from column 1A to the value from column 2A and if these are equal, then return the value from column 2B & 2D for every row in Dataset 1. Either creating a new dataframe or adding it to dataframe 1. Then I should get the following:

Dataset 3:

```
 Column_3A Column_3B Column_3C Column_3D
1         1         a         r         3
2         1         b         r         3
3         2         b        12        NA
4         2         d        12        NA
5         2         f        12        NA
6         3         e         d         1

Column_3A <- c(1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3)
Column_3A <- c(1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3)
Column_3B <- c("a", "b", "b", "d", "f", "e", "a")
Column_3C <- c("r", "r", 12, 12, 12, "d", "d")
Column_3D <- c(3, 3, NA, NA, NA, 1, 1)
Dataset_3 <- data.frame(Column_3A, Column_3B, Column_3C, Column_3D)
```

Comment: Might be easier to rename and `merge/*join`? Might need to split first though.

Answer (score 0):

You could `left_join` and remove the column which you don't need

```
library(dplyr)

left_join(Dataset_1, Dataset_2, by = c("Column_1A" = "Column_2A")) %>%
    select(-Column_2C) %>%
    rename_all(~paste0("Column_3", LETTERS[seq_along(.)]))

#  Column_3A Column_3B Column_3C Column_3D
#1         1         a         r         3
#2         1         b         r         3
#3         2         b        12        NA
#4         2         d        12        NA
#5         2         f        12        NA
#6         3         e         d         1
#7         3         a         d         1
```